# Find the area of a circle that is inscribed in a circular sector with a radius $R$ and an angle $2x$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The circle within the sector touches the radii R and the arc.
So what is the area of the inscribed circle?
The answer is actually  $$S = \pi R^2\frac{\sin^2x}{(1+\sin x)^2}$$
How can I derive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $\;O\;$ the center of the big circle from where the circular sector is taken, and let $\;M\;$ be the little circle's center with radius $\;r\;$,  and $\;A,B\;$ the two tangent points between circle $\;M\;$ and the the two radii formining the sector.

If we put $\;t:=$the distance between $\;O\;$ and the inner circle, then taking the straight angle triangle $\;\Delta AMO\;$ we get:

$$\sin x=\frac r{r+t}\;\;\text{and also}\;\;r=R-(t+r)\implies t=R-2r\implies$$

$$r=(r+R-2r)\sin x\implies r=(R-r)\sin x\implies r=\frac{R\sin x}{1+\sin x}$$

so finally

$$S=\pi R^2\frac{\sin^2x}{(1+\sin x)^2}$$

Comment: Let's say that the tangent point between the inscribed circle and the arc of the big circle is T.
I've noticed that if we prove that T, M and O are in a straight line, then everything's really easy. How can I do that?

And I don't actually understand your way of solving this problem.
$$\sin x = \frac {AM}{OM} = \frac {r}{t}$$ Why did you write $r+t$ and not $t$ instead of OM?
I think you actually meant $t$ and not $r+t$ when you wrote that.

Comment: If I'm correct that you wrote $r+t$ instead of $t$ by accident, then from what I see later on in the solution is that you implied that T, M and O are in the same straight line (where T is the tangent point between the little circle and the arc of the big circle).
How do you know that and how can you prove it? Thanks.

Comment: $\;OM=t+r=$the distance between $\;O\;$ and the inner, little circle + the little circle's radius. This is one of the main reasons why this kind of problems go way easier with adiagram with letters...

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake in my answer. Again, it's hard not to get confused without a diagram.

Comment: But do you know how to prove the later point that T, M and O are in the same straight line?

Comment: Because all this can't be done if we don't know if those 3 points are in a straight line.

Comment: I really don't know what three points you're talking about, **but** perhaps you mean both circles' centers and the tangent point on the arc, and then this follows at once from the well known theorem from Euclidean Geometry: When ywo circles are tangent to each other, the line joining their centers (or its continuations) intersects the tangency point.

Comment: And again:I'm not sure what point you call $\;T\;$ to...

Comment: Oh, thanks, I've found the proof here: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII11.html.
And if you read my other comments, you'd see that I defined T: "(where T is the tangent point between the little circle and the arc of the big circle)". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKh55.jpg)

$\sin⁡x=\dfrac{r}{R-r}$

$⇒r=(R-r)sin⁡x$

$⇒r+r  \sin⁡x= R  \sin⁡x$

$⇒r(1+ \sin⁡x )=R  \sin⁡x$

$⇒r^2 (1+ \sin⁡x )^2=R^2   \sin^2⁡x$

$⇒r^2=R^2    \dfrac{\sin^2⁡x}{(1+ \sin⁡x )^2} $

$⇒S=πr^2=πR^2   \dfrac{ \sin^2⁡x}{(1+ \sin⁡x )^2}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both your answers and questions :)

Comment: thanks  @mrtaurho